# cannot import name 'unicode' from 'statsmodels.compat' (c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\__init__.py)

Tags: python, statsmodels

I tried to import statsmodels in python, using

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

but I failed.

I got an error

> `cannot import name 'unicode' from 'statsmodels.compat'`

I reinstalled and upgraded `statsmodels` package, but the error remains.

Could you help me to fix this error?

This is my traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-085740203b77> in <module>
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py in <module>
      7 from . import regression
      8 from .regression.linear_model import OLS, GLS, WLS, GLSAR
----> 9 from .regression.recursive_ls import RecursiveLS
     10 from .regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg
     11 from .regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\recursive_ls.py in <module>
     10 import pandas as pd
     11 
---> 12 from statsmodels.compat import unicode
     13 from statsmodels.tools.data import _is_using_pandas
     14 from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel import (

ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode' from 'statsmodels.compat' (c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I included traceback as you said.

Comment: try pip install statsmodels --upgrade

Comment: I tried. I got message 
"requirement already upto date: ~~~~
requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade".

Comment: what about pip install unicode--upgrade

Comment: I've just tried and I got error message
" ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unicode--upgrade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for unicode--upgrade"

Comment: Your `statsmodel` package seems messed up. It tries to import something from itself, that it does not implement. It looks like it consists of modules from different versions. What version does pip report for that package?

Comment: pip reports (0.10.1) version for statsmodel.
I could find it when i used "pip install statsmodels --upgrade".
pip reported "Requirement already up-to-date: statsmodels in c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.10.1)".

Comment: Please check if the file `c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\__init__.py` looks like [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/v0.10.1/statsmodels/compat/__init__.py), i.e. if the name `unicode` is imported from the `python.py` module in [line 5](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/v0.10.1/statsmodels/compat/__init__.py#L5) and if that name is made public via `__all__` in [line 19](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/v0.10.1/statsmodels/compat/__init__.py#L19).

Comment: I found that the file exactly looks like the code you showed me. While I was trying to find the statsmodels in my c drive, i found that statsmodels was also installed via anaconda3. And this statsmodel's version was 0.9.0. I deleted this anaconda statsmodels. Finally I succeded! Now statsmodel module works well! Thanks a lot! I wouldn't have solve my problem if you had not helped me. I'm glad to meet you here.